# Plot state of boolean variables as bar over time

Tags: r, ggplot2, naniar

I am trying to do a visualisation on the state of multiple boolean variables.
I managed to get a hacky solution using `naniar`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(naniar)
a <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE,FALSE)
b <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,FALSE)
c <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,FALSE)

data.frame(a,b,c) %>%
  mutate_all(~ if_else(., NA, FALSE)) %>%
  vis_miss()
```

[image: missing value visualisation using naniar]

Obviously that is abusing this library and doesn't have the right labels.
How could I achieve the same thing in ggplot (say with a `colour` variable of `enabled` TRUE or FALSE)?

Comment: Could you give examples/describe what you would want the plot to look like?

Comment: `visdat::vis_mis()` is returning a `ggplot` object. So you may alternatively try customizing its output, if you otherwise are happy with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first transform your data to a longer format using `pivot_longer`. You could use `geom_tile` to create a heatmap like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(a,b,c) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = a:c) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = factor(ID), fill = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  labs(fill = "Enabled", y = 'ID', x = "Name")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>